# How to create button that will make a window visible

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have this window:

```
<div id="window" style="display:none">
</div>
 <script>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#window").kendoWindow({
        "modal":true,
        "iframe":false,
        "draggable":true,
        "pinned":false,
        "title":"Login",
        "resizable":true,
        "content":null,
        "width":600,
        "actions":["Close"]
    });
});
  </script>
 </section>
 </div>
```

It has display:none so it doesn't show at start.

How do I now create a button to make the window visible?

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the window just need to call

$("#window").data("kendoWindow").center().open();

I always add center in to make sure if the window has been previously opened, then moved, then closed and reopened again, it will be back in the center of the page.

See sample... http://jsbin.com/AGuJAve/1/edit